# how would i iteratively translate my array input to integers

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

suppose i have the following input as a multidimensional list

```
chain = [['.','.','.','.','.','.','.']
        ['.','.','.','.','.','.','.'],
        ['.','.','.','.','.','.','.']]
```

how can i iterate through the loop and count each item.

Answer (score 1):

```
# your mapping
m = '.C-|'

# iterate rows then inside iterate columns
out = [[m.index(c) for c in r] for r in grid]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just make use of the numpy library as follows:

```
import numpy as np
grid = np.array([['.','.','.','.','.','.','.'],
        ['.','C','-','C','-','C','.'],
        ['.','.','.','|','.','.','.'],
        ['.','.','.','C','.','.','.'],
        ['.','.','.','.','.','.','.'],
        ['.','.','.','.','.','.','.'],
        ['.','.','.','.','.','.','.']])

grid = np.where(grid=='.', '0', grid)
grid = np.where(grid=='C', '1', grid)
grid = np.where(grid=='-', '2', grid)
grid = np.where(grid=='|', '3', grid)
```